# How to load UWP app settings and handle errors

Tags: c#, uwp

I have an UWP app which needs to load some settings from files.

I do this in [app.xaml.cs OnLaunched event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application.onlaunched?view=winrt-19041).
I make a few async calls inside this method. This works on my development machine when run in Visual Studio and from `bin` folder, but it crashes on test machine.

I added `try`/`catch` block with `dialog` to display the error, but that does not work. The app just hangs on splash screen when I throw an error for testing on my dev machine.

What is the correct way to load app settings and handle errors?

Comment: Could share more detail about the exception message, or share the code that how to  load setting from file?

Comment: There is no exception message. The app just crashes on splash screen. I suspect that the issue is with the RemoveAll line of code below, but my question is really how to get the error message display from app_xaml.cs.

 JsonConvert.PopulateObject(myJsonStringLoadedFromFile, myList);
myList.RemoveAll(e => e.something == something);

Comment: Does `UnhandledException`  triggered ?

Comment: Windows Application log has: Fault bucket 2264841606854554960, type 5
 Event Name: MoAppCrash
 Response: Not available
 Cab Id: 0

Is that it?

Comment: Not that, please check [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application.unhandledexception?view=winrt-19041) for details

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. How can I tell if unhandled exception occurred? I cannot replicate on dev machine. On test machine there is the Windows event log entry

Comment: Could you share a [mcve] for us, I will debug base on that.

Comment: I'll try. It's hard as I cannot replicate on dev machine...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225399/discussion-between-under-and-nico-zhu-msft).